# DatabaseException: Class is missing a constructor with no arguments

Tags: android, exception, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying retrieve data from my firebase database and display it in TextViews in a ListView. However, I'm getting a 'missing constructor' exception on this line: `Clients clients = clientsSnapshot.getValue(Clients.class);`.

Here's the full exception:
[image]

Not sure how to fix it. I'm not very experienced in either firebase or android development so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers guys!

```
public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity{

    ListView listviewClients;
    List<Clients> clientsList;

    DatabaseReference databaseClients;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);

        listviewClients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewClients);
        databaseClients = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clients");

        clientsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseClients.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                clientsList.clear();

                for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot clientsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Clients clients = clientsSnapshot.getValue(Clients.class);

                    clientsList.add(clients);
                }
                ClientsList adapter = new ClientsList(ViewProfile.this, clientsList);
                listviewClients.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
    }
}
```

**Clients.java:**

```
public class Clients {

    String clientName;
    String clientCareer;
    Boolean techCB;
    Boolean mediCB;
    Boolean renewableEnergyNF;
    Boolean googleNF;
    Boolean novartisNF;
    Boolean teslaNF;
    Boolean fbLRS;
    Boolean applLRS;
    Boolean yhooLRS;
    Boolean eurusdCB;
    Boolean usdrubCU;
    Boolean silverCO;
    Boolean goldCO;
    Boolean gbpusdCU;
    Boolean nsdqI;
    Boolean sp500I;


//    public Clients(String id, String name, String career, Boolean techCB, Boolean mediCB, Boolean renewableEnergyNF, Boolean googleNF, Boolean novartisNF, Boolean teslaNF, Boolean fbLRS, Boolean applLRS, Boolean yhooLRS, Boolean eurusdCB, Boolean usdrubCU, Boolean silverCO, Boolean goldCO, Boolean gbpusdCU, Boolean nsdqI, Boolean sp500I) {
//
//    }

    public Clients(String id, String clientCareer, String clientName, Boolean techCB, Boolean mediCB, Boolean renewableEnergyNF,
                   Boolean googleNF, Boolean novartisNF, Boolean teslaNF, Boolean fbLRS, Boolean applLRS, Boolean yhooLRS, Boolean eurusdCB,
                   Boolean usdrubCU, Boolean silverCO, Boolean goldCO, Boolean gbpusdCU, Boolean nsdqI, Boolean sp500I) {

        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.clientCareer = clientCareer;
        this.techCB = techCB;
        this.mediCB = mediCB;
        this.renewableEnergyNF = renewableEnergyNF;
        this.googleNF = googleNF;
        this.novartisNF = novartisNF;
        this.teslaNF = teslaNF;
        this.fbLRS = fbLRS;
        this.applLRS = applLRS;
        this.yhooLRS = yhooLRS;
        this.eurusdCB = eurusdCB;
        this.usdrubCU = usdrubCU;
        this.silverCO = silverCO;
        this.goldCO = goldCO;
        this.gbpusdCU = gbpusdCU;
        this.nsdqI = nsdqI;
        this.sp500I = sp500I;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public String getClientCareer() {
        return clientCareer;
    }

    public Boolean getTechCB() {
        return techCB;
    }

    public Boolean getMediCB() {
        return mediCB;
    }

    public Boolean getRenewableEnergyNF() {
        return renewableEnergyNF;
    }

    public Boolean getGoogleNF() {
        return googleNF;
    }

    public Boolean getNovartisNF() {
        return novartisNF;
    }

    public Boolean getTeslaNF() {
        return teslaNF;
    }

    public Boolean getFbLRS() {
        return fbLRS;
    }

    public Boolean getApplLRS() {
        return applLRS;
    }

    public Boolean getYhooLRS() {
        return yhooLRS;
    }

    public Boolean getEurusdCB() {
        return eurusdCB;
    }

    public Boolean getUsdrubCU() {
        return usdrubCU;
    }

    public Boolean getSilverCO() {
        return silverCO;
    }

    public Boolean getGoldCO() {
        return goldCO;
    }

    public Boolean getGbpusdCU() {
        return gbpusdCU;
    }

    public Boolean getNsdqI() {
        return nsdqI;
    }

    public Boolean getSp500I() {
        return sp500I;
    }
```

Comment: `Clients` class doesn't have a no argument constructor

Comment: Which part of the error message do you need help with? Do you know what a constructor is? Do you know what arguments are? Once you understand the terminology, you should be able to figure out how to fix the error.

Comment: post the `Clients` class code..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't know the definition for a constructor but it's usually the public _____ (){}? and what I know of arguments is that they're like parameters. If you could help me with any knowledge I'd be very happy:D

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Posted. Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Model class add :  no argument `constructor`

```
public class Clients {
    private String name;  //your variables 
    ...
    ...

    public Clients (){ }  //no argument constructor
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

> what I know of arguments is that they're like parameters

Yes, arguments and parameters are the same thing.

> I don't know the definition for a constructor but it's usually the public _____ (){}?

Yes, this is correct. The error message is telling you that your `Clients` class does not have a constructor which does not have any arguments. If you create a class with no constructors, the no argument constructor is generated automatically. You get the error because you have a `Clients` constructor which takes arguments. Therefore, you need to explicitly provide one without any arguments for it to work correctly with Firebase.

p.s. You should use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`. For more details, you should learn more about the difference between primitive types and wrapper objects.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I've just tried to immerse myself in it and this is very helpful! Cheers, have a good day.